# Deleting a row with a self-referencing foreign key

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys

I have a MySQL table whose definition is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `guestbook` (
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ThreadId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `ThreadId` (`ThreadId`),
  CONSTRAINT `guestbook_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ThreadId`) REFERENCES `guestbook` (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and currently there's only 1 row in the table:

```
mysql> select * from guestbook;
+-----+----------+
| Id  | ThreadId |
+-----+----------+
| 211 |      211 |
+-----+----------+
```

The problem is that there's no way to delete this row without breaking the constraint.

```
mysql> delete from guestBook;
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`polaris`.`guestbook`, CONSTRAINT `guestbook_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ThreadId`) REFERENCES `guestbook` (`Id`))
```

As the ThreadId column was defined not null, it is also impossible to set the ThreadId to a different value temporarily to delete the row. Is there a way to delete the row without changing the definition of the table or dropping the entire table?

Comment: A row being a child row for itself is strange.

Comment: Wow that's just awesome, you've created a table structure that once it has rows you need to turn off constraints to delete the last row. Too bad the ID wasn't 22.

Comment: @Conrad: Yeah, but this can always happen with any self-referencing foreign keys. :$

Comment: @K.J. true but usually the "parent ID" is nullable.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can temporarily disable foreign key constraints with this query:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the best way for now.

Comment: Where should this query get run? On which table and how? You would better edit your answer and make it more clear.

Answer (score 9):

If you put an `ON DELETE CASCADE` action on your foreign key, you should be able to delete rows that are self-referencing.

```
CONSTRAINT `guestbook_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ThreadId`) REFERENCES `guestbook` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

The benefit this has over using `ON DELETE SET NULL` is that you don't have to alter your schema to make the "ThreadId" column nullable.

Comment: I do not understand why this answer not the best and correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

There are several workarounds.  The approach suggested by others ...

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

... will disable the foreign keys of every table.  This is not suitable for use in a shared environment.

Another approach is to drop the foreign key using

```
ALTER TABLE `guestbook` 
    DROP FOREIGN KEY `guestbook_ibfk_1`
/
```

We can sort out the data using DML, and then reinstate the foreign key using:

```
ALTER TABLE `guestbook` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `guestbook_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ThreadId`) 
        REFERENCES `guestbook` (`Id`)
/
```

But is there a way to change the data without executing any DDL?  Well,  we can insert a new record and change the current record to reference it:

```
INSERT INTO `guestbook`  VALUES (212, 211)
/
UPDATE `guestbook` 
SET `ThreadId` = 212
WHERE `Id` = 211
/
```

Astute observers will have noticed that we have still ended up with a co-dependency, only  between records.  So we haven't really advanced; we now have two records we cannot delete, instead of one. (Incidentally this applies to whatever DML we might execute while the foreign key is dropped or disabled).   So, perhaps we need to reconsider of the data model.  Are we modelling a graph with circular dependencies or a hierarchy?

A hierarchical data structure needs at least one root node, a record on which other records can depend but which itself depends on no record. The usual way of implementing this is to make the foreign key column optional.  At the toppermost level of the hierarchy the record must have a NULL in that column.  Whether there should be only one such root node or whether several would be allowed is a matter for your business rules.

```
ALTER TABLE `guestbook` MODIFY `ThreadId`  int(10) unsigned
/
```

In modelling terms this is not different from a record which is its own master, but it is a more intuitive solution.

Answer (score 6):

The inability to delete a self-referencing row is a longstanding [known bug/outstanding feature request in MySQL](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=7412).

In many situations where you rub up against this problem you can NULL the foreign key before executing the delete, so your workaround affects only the rows you intend (uses the same WHERE clause).

Comment: Simplest solution in our use case. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ya temporarily disable the foreign key

```
set foreign_key_checks=0;
```

Comment: looks like it's foreign_key_checks, not foreign_key_constraints. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you set an `ON DELETE SET NULL` on my Foreign Key, it let's me delete a self-referencing. If I don't specify an `ON DELETE`, MySQL defaults to `RESTRICT`.

Of course, make sure the column is `NULLABLE`. You may also try `SET DEFAULT` depending on what the default is. But remember `NO ACTION` is just an alias to `RESTRICT` in MySQL!

Only tested on MySQL 5.6 (which was not released when this question was originally posted).